# How to tell if a system is running as a live USB from BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, live-usb, iso

I'm working on making an ISO image I can burn to a USB device as a live system. In order to install to the internal drive of the system that booted the live USB, I have an icon on the desktop to launch the installer.

After installation, I want to remove the icon. In order to do this, I was going to make a script that detected whether the system was running as a live USB or was actually installed. Is there a way to detect this from BASH?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, no guarantees 'cause no actual difference. But can be detected by detect the property of the device your root filesystem reside on, like a overlayfs with the lower fs on a loop device which is on a USB device. `udevadm` might help.

Comment: How about have the installer do something. Such that the installed OS is different (maybe just a flag, to tell it not to show the icon).

Answer (score 3):

You can examine the entry for the root file system in `/proc/mounts`. If you boot from CD, you likely use iso9660 as a file system and have a device like `/dev/sr0`.

Of course, you can just create a file somewhere as part of the installation and use the presence of this file as an indicator.

Comment: that `/dev/sr0` helped me get to me what I figured out I could do. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A linux live OS (usb or cd) has its filesystem stored in RAM, but a regular OS persists data on a partition on disk. We can detect this difference in bash with two commands.

1. You can get info about the filesystem containing your home directory with

   ```
   df ~
   ```

This will give you something like "overlay", "aufs", or "/dev/sda1" (plus other information)

2. You can  get the list of partitions with

   ```
   cat /proc/partitions
   ```

Therefore, if the file system reported in the first command isn't included in the list of partitions from the second command then you're running a live OS.

Putting it all together:

```
full_fs=$(df ~ | tail -1 | awk '{print $1;}')  # /dev/sda1
fs=$(basename $full_fs)                        # sda1
if grep -q "$fs" /proc/partitions; then
  echo "regular linux install. NOT a live OS"
else
  echo "is a live OS running from RAM"
fi
```

Update!

The filesystem won't be listed as a partition for containers too. This is because the partition table reported from within the container will be the partitions of the host OS. If distinguishing between containers and a linux live OS is required then you should add one more condition:

```
if cat /proc/1/cgroup | tail -1 | grep -q "container"; then
  echo "linux container"
else
  full_fs=$(df ~ | tail -1 | awk '{print $1;}')  # /dev/sda1
  fs=$(basename $full_fs)                        # sda1
  if grep -q "$fs" /proc/partitions; then
    echo "regular linux install"
  else
    echo "live OS running from RAM"
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can do `lsblk | grep 'sr0'` and if it finds that `sr0` then more than likely it is running as a live usb. Even if it is actually installed with a live usb plugged in that `sr0` only shows up if the live usb is actually booted.

Comment: The `sr0` is a CD, not USB storage. Instead of grep, you could use `lsblk /dev/sr0`. I get a line for `sr0` just for having a CD drive, without even a CD being present in the drive.